# How to draw in C++ with Mouse Down Event

Tags: c++, drawing, mouseevent, paint

I wanna draw some pixels with mouse and i wanna do it in C++ just like in Paint but so far i couldnt get it working.

What i have done:

```
// NewPaint.cpp : main project file.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <Winuser.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitle(L"PaintER"); // Set text of the console so you can find the window
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow(); // Get the HWND
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd); // Get the DC from that HWND
    textbackgroundcolor(WHITE); // Background color
    textcolor(BLACK); // Text color
    POINT p; // Pointer
    while(1) // Smt like  mouse button 1 
    {
        if (ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p)) // Mouse position
        {
            SetPixel(hdc, p.x, p.y, RGB(0,0,0)); // Draw black pixels
        }
    }
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc); // Release the DC
    DeleteDC(hdc); // Delete the DC
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for this and using Windows 7. I heard these could be inportant infos..

I dont have  i only got GDI+ references so if you know a way to use it for this please let me know.

I need coding examples and explanations with it as i've given in my code.

Comment: No, not like that.  Like this: http://win32-framework.sourceforge.net/Tutorials/tutorial3.htm

Comment: *sighs* He needs to start at the beginning of that tutorial, or better yet pick up a copy of Programming Windows 5th Edition

Comment: @johnathon i havent used c++ nor tried to understand until now. so yea im at the begining of this.